# как отправить фото на сайт и получить ответ с помощью python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, веб-программирование, requests

Недавно в сети появилась нейросеть, которая делает фото в стиле аниме из вашего фото: https://h5.tu.qq.com/web/ai-2d/cartoon/index . Не подскажете как отправить фото на сайт и получить уже измененное обратно

Я попытался использовать библиотеку requests, но получал следющий html-файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /ai-2d/cartoon/index</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

POST на color.photofuneditor.com/ceremony-vegas
Параметр fileToUpload
Содержание параметра - base64 картинки

```
 import requests
   import base64


with open("nums.jpeg", "rb") as image_file:
    image_hash = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode("utf-8")

encoded_image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,{}'.format(image_hash)
payload = {'fileToUpload': encoded_image}

r = requests.post('http://color.photofuneditor.com/ceremony-vegas', 
data=payload)

 if r.status_code == 200:
    image_url = 
'http://color.photofuneditor.com/output/{}'.format(r.json() 
['file_link'])
    r = requests.get(image_url)

    with open('new_image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```